# 405 Method Not Allowed after intake form submission s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to run an intake form on my web application that is being hosted on my S3 bucket. When the form is submitted, it is supposed to be parsed and then created into an event on my google calendar through the google api. However, whenever I submit the form, this error appears:

`405 Method Not Allowed Code: MethodNotAllowed Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource. Method: POST ResourceType: OBJECT RequestId: 14QRGC2900ERK7B2 HostId: MLcJMpOhp2AgATU9BNX5FkcoW/znBDBjrItgU0aQEhd9nxAsC8ExVd+9qMOH3ngrK9WSbXsenuo=`

I understand that the error is referring to the form not allowing for the use of the POST method, but I am not sure how to allow the POST method to be used